# inputAcessoryView being displayed with UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have overridden the `-inputAccessoryView:` method in a UIViewController which returns a view which is displayed on top of the keyboard which is shown while editing a `UITextField` on the viewController's view.

```
-(UIView *)inputAccessoryView;
```

I am also presenting a UIAlertController from the viewController.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Save Profile" message:@"You have made changes to your profile. Do you want to save them?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //Code to save the profile.
    }]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

As you can see I have not added any textField to the UIAlertController.

Weirdly, the inputAcessoryView turns up at the bottom of the screen when the UIAlertController is presented.

Is this a bug, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your input accessory view to something other than `inputAccessoryView`.
e.g. keyboardaccessoryView.

Then add the following line

```
self.m_textFieldName.inputAccessoryView = [self keyboardInputAccessoryView];
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use the name 'inputAccessoryView'**

This will fix..!

```
    - (UIView *)CustominputAccessoryView {
    if (!keyboardinputAccessoryView) {
        CGRect accessFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40.0);
        keyboardinputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:accessFrame];
        keyboardinputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor  colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:0.6];
        UIButton *compButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        compButton.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-60, 0.0, 50, 40.0);
        [compButton setTitle: @"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        compButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [compButton setTitleColor:self.view.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [compButton addTarget:self action:@selector(completeCurrentWord:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [keyboardinputAccessoryView addSubview:compButton];
    }
    return keyboardinputAccessoryView;
}
```

*keyboardinputAccessoryView* is just a UIView

```
@property (readonly, retain) UIView *keyboardinputAccessoryView;
```

then make 'CustominputAccessoryView' as inputAccessoryView of your textField

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 textField.inputAccessoryView = [self CustominputAccessoryView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, you can try

```
textFirld.resignFirstResponder()
```

Before you present the AlertViewController.

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have property for UITextField like inputAccessoryView so it is over riding it. If possible

Just change the name of the view from

```
-(UIView *)inputAccessoryView;
```

to some name

```
-(UIView *)alertDisplayView;
```

This will fix..! Exactly I don't no why u have taken view with name inputAccessoryView..!

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: The input accessory view is being returned to be shown on top of the keyboard for another UITextField which is present on the view controllers view.

Comment: Dont use name inputAccessoryView in any of the methods as it may cause those issues. So, without using it I think inputAccessoryView will not shown in any textfield.

Comment: The point is, I need to show the inputAccessoryView in the current UIVIewController. The question is why the inputAcessoryView is being shown while the UIAlertController is being presented. I am not sure whether you even understand my question.